# How do I center a boxed 'Verbatim'?

Tags: verbatim, fancyvrb

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

%===

\begin{document}


\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small, frame=single, xrightmargin=5cm]
Text.
\end{Verbatim}


\end{document}
```

I'm trying to center the box, but I couldn't find any way of doing it. Any comments? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may be overkill, but `tcolorbox` can do this easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small, frame=single]
Text.
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This needs one to hardcode the width of the verbatim content in the line `\begin{minipage}{8cm}`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `BVerbatim`; for boxing, use `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newsavebox{\FVerbBox}
\newenvironment{FVerbatim}
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{center}
  \begin{lrbox}{\FVerbBox}
  \begin{BVerbatim}}
 {\end{BVerbatim}
  \end{lrbox}
  \fbox{\usebox{\FVerbBox}}
  \end{center}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{FVerbatim}[fontsize=\small]
Text.
\end{FVerbatim}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to remove the box border?

Comment: @HappyFace Remove `\fbox` and a pair of braces.