# New environment for minipage and colorbox

Tags: environments, verbatim

I would like to create a new environment that would automate the following code:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\begin{minipage}{5.8in}
\color{black}
\begin{verbatim}

<Some verbatim text here>

\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}}
\fcolorbox{blue!30}{gray!7}{\box0}
```

I'm pretty new to Latex, so I apologize if this question is not clear or if there is some obvious mistake.  I also want to say that this site is **fantastic** and extremely helpful for new Latex users like myself.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably `fancyvrb` is what you're looking for. Possibly you can adapt the code here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182489/4427

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapting from code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182489/4427)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newsavebox{\FVerbBox}
\newenvironment{FVerbatim}
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{center}
  \begin{lrbox}{\FVerbBox}
  \begin{minipage}{5.8in}
  \begin{Verbatim}}
 {\end{Verbatim}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}
  \fcolorbox{blue!30}{gray!7}{\usebox{\FVerbBox}}
  \end{center}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{FVerbatim}[fontsize=\small]
Text.
With { \ strange /##& characters
\end{FVerbatim}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version with additional vertical spaces. The interaction with `Verbatim` makes it somewhat difficult to guess at the right proportions, just experiment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newsavebox{\FVerbBox}
\newenvironment{FVerbatim}
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{center}
  \vspace{1ex} % additional space above the frame
  \begin{lrbox}{\FVerbBox}
  \begin{minipage}{5.8in}
  \vspace*{4ex} % additional space before the verbatim material
  \begin{Verbatim}}
 {\end{Verbatim}
  \vspace{1ex} % additional space after the verbatim material
  \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}
  \fcolorbox{blue!30}{gray!7}{\usebox{\FVerbBox}}
  \vspace{1ex} % additional space after the frame
  \end{center}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{FVerbatim}[fontsize=\small]
Text.
With { \ strange /##& characters
\end{FVerbatim}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For fancier boxes, you can have a look at `tcolorbox`

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is extremely helpful.  One more thing though: is there some way I could control the amount of space between the top of the frame of the text box and the start of the text?  It would be ideal if I could also control the spacing between the bottom of the frame and the text as well.  I'm starting to really like Latex :)

Comment: Thanks! This is good, but I should have described things better in my question: I was wondering about the amount of space between the frame of the box and the text _inside_ the box instead of the amount of space between the box and the text outside the box.  I really appreciate the help.